# Spring-boot 2 ignoring Hikari specific properties

Tags: spring-boot, hikaricp

I'm trying to configure some Hikari specific properties for the datasource, and can't figure out how to do that left alone, that I don't even see how it suppose to work.

According to the [Spring-boot doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#spring.datasource.hikari) you should be able to configure lots of additional props, for example, `spring.datasource.hikari.transaction-isolation`. So I have `application.properties` file with a content

```
spring.application.name=My App

# DB 
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=dbname
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=passw
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.datasource.hikari.minimumIdle=5
spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize=30
spring.datasource.hikari.transaction-isolation=TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
```

From what I understand from the docs, this should be enough for Spring-boot 2 to initialize Hickory datasource with the additional properties. However, when I run my application I can see that the datasource created with only generic `spring.datasource.*` properties.

I debugged application initialisation and looked at `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration` class. I can see Spring uses Hikari datasource and creates an instance of HikariDataSource.class, but created datasource doesn't have any specific properties set. What I don't understand, is how it even possible to have some additional properties if the *properties* parameter has the actual type of `DataSourceProperties` which has no knowledge of any hikari specific properties. I thought it would be something hikari specific but it is not.

```
/**
 * Hikari DataSource configuration.
 */
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@ConditionalOnClass(HikariDataSource.class)
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(DataSource.class)
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "spring.datasource.type", havingValue = "com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource",
        matchIfMissing = true)
static class Hikari {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.hikari")
    HikariDataSource dataSource(DataSourceProperties properties) {
        HikariDataSource dataSource = createDataSource(properties, HikariDataSource.class);
        if (StringUtils.hasText(properties.getName())) {
            dataSource.setPoolName(properties.getName());
        }
        return dataSource;
    }

}
```

I can imagine that there maybe another call to configure the datasource later, but I can't find it and when inspecting datasource, at runtime, I can see they not set. I must be missing something here, so any help would be appreciated.

P.S. I also tried to use manual configuration but hit an another issue with Flyway.

Comment: Make `Hikari` public

Comment: @user7294900 Hikari is a class within Spring's DataSourceConfiguration class, so that' not an option.